# Excel VBA: Argument Not Optional Error When Adding To An Array

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue with the below code. Whenever it gets to the last line, it throws the error "Argument Not Optional", and will not compile. I have no clue what argument it is talking about.

```
Option Base 1
Dim temp As New ProductionItem 'Production Item is a class that I made
Dim Arr() As Collection
ReDim Arr(5)
Dim coll As New Collection
coll.Add temp
Arr(1) = coll
```

Comment: A `Collection` is an object.  If you want to set `Arr(1)` to be the collection `coll`, you will need to `Set Arr(1) = coll`.  (But are you really intending `Arr` to be an array of Collections of `ProductionItem`?)

Comment: And the missing argument it is talking about is the `key`, because without the `Set` keyword, VBA was trying to invoke the *default property* of the `Collection` object, that is, `col1.Item(key)` where the parameter `key` is mandatory...

Answer (score 1):

Only need **Set**

```
Option Base 1

Sub fun()
    Dim Arr() As Collection
    ReDim Arr(5)
    Dim coll As New Collection
    coll.Add 1
    Set Arr(1) = coll
End Sub
```